# Updating a img in a function (and a switch)

Tags: javascript, html, image

Om trying to update a img(damage) with a onclick function.

```
<img id="damage" src="100.png">
<img id="healing" onclick="heal()" src="healing.png">
```

img(damage) changes from a variable with a switch(prosent), when the site is opened.

When i click on img(healing) i want the variable(prosent) to change, so the img(damage) change.

```
var liv = document.getElementById('damage');
var prosent = 0;
function heal() {
        prosent += 10;
}

switch (prosent){
            case 100:
                liv.src = "100.png";
                break;
            case 99:
                liv.src = "99.png";
                break; 

                all the way down to 0.. 
}
```

...

So, how can i make it update?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the switch inside a function and call it from heal()

```
var liv = document.getElementById('damage');
var prosent = 0;
function heal() {
        prosent += 10;
        update();
}

function update() {
    switch (prosent){
            case 100:
                liv.src = "100.png";
                break;
            case 99:
                liv.src = "99.png";
                break; 

                all the way down to 0.. 
    }
}
```

but it would be much better if you wrote your update function like this:

```
function update() {
    liv.src = prosent + ".png";
}
```

or even better:

```
var liv = document.getElementById('damage');
var prosent = 0;
function heal() {
        prosent += 10;
        liv.src = prosent + '.png';
}
```

easier eh ?

Comment: Thanks! I feel stupid now, making a switch with 101 cases.. :)

Comment: No one is stupid. All of us are just learning. :) Althought there are some extreme cases. :D But that's not your case :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put the `switch` statement inside of your `heal()` method, but you can forgo it entirely and use string concatenation to dynamically update your image `src` instead.

(I have added a few statements updating the `alt` text of the image as well, because that is good accessibility practice and it makes the demo easier to understand.)

```js
var liv = document.getElementById('damage');
var prosent = +liv.alt;

function heal() {
  prosent += 10;
  liv.src = (liv.alt = prosent) + '.png';
}
```

```html
<img id="damage" src="100.png" alt="100">
<img id="healing" onclick="heal()" src="healing.png">
```

Comment: Maybe it would be better if we explain to the user that + operator in `var prosent = +liv.alt;` is a javascript "trick" to convert a string value to number. And `(liv.alt = prosent)` sets liv.alt property with the value of prosent then concatenates to '.png' and then assigns it to liv.src.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
<img id="damage" src="100.png">
<img id="healing" onclick="heal()" src="healing.png">


    var liv = document.getElementById('damage');
    var prosent = 0;
    heal = function() {
        prosent += 10;
        if (prosent > 0) {
        liv.src = prosent + ".png";
    }
```

Notice i made the heal function available in the global scope, since i'm not sure where your javascript scope is located. Anyways, my example works.